# Nested cross-validation: different hparams for each outer fold?

Tags: cross-validation, model-selection

Suppose I have a dataset and two estimators, each with different hyperparameters. I want to select the best estimator and make sure it generalizes well. Therefore, I need to use nested cross-validation to find the best hyperparameters for each estimator, and then, to select the best model.

The pseudocode for the nested CV loop would look something like this:

```
for outer_train, outer_test in outer_cv:
    # find best hyperparameters by cross-validation over the data in outer_train for each of the estimators.
    # score performance of the best-hyperparameter model against outer_test set.

select model with best outer loop performance.
```

By the time this nested loop is finished, I will have 2 models for each fold of outer cross-validation: that corresponding to the best hyperparameters found for model_1 and model_2. But the optimal hyperparameters can vary from fold to fold.

If my outer cross-validation has 5 folds, then I'd end up with 10 different models. How do I select the final, winning model to be used in my dataset?

Comment: Usually different models are build using different validation set. Cross-validation aims at measuring generalisation performance. See [How to split basics](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/576145/does-using-grid-search-for-hyperparemeters-make-test-set-redundant/576179#576179)